# Проблема в FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Проблема в `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. Выдает такую ошибку:

> Error:(73, 86) error: constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: FirebaseRecyclerOptions
>   found: Class,int,Class,Query
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>   where T,VH are type-variables:
>   T extends Object declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
>   VH extends ViewHolder declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Уже и документацию читал, и код менял. Ничего не получается. Прошу помощи в решении проблемы. Я новечек у меня не получается это зделать.

```
private void loadData() {
    Query query = fNotesDatabase.orderByValue();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(

            NoteModel.class,
            R.layout.activity_notes,
            NoteViewHolder.class,
            query

    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final NoteViewHolder viewHolder, NoteModel model, int position) {
            final String noteId = getRef(position).getKey();

            fNotesDatabase.child(noteId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("title") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("timestamp")) {
                        String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
                        String timestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString();

                        viewHolder.setNoteTitle(title);
                        //viewHolder.setNoteTime(timestamp);

                        GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                        viewHolder.setNoteTime(getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(timestamp), getApplicationContext()));

                        viewHolder.noteCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(NotesMine.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }
```

**Вот изменения в коде.**

```
public class NotesMine extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
private RecyclerView mNotesList;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;

private DatabaseReference fNotesDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    mNotesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.notes_list);

    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mNotesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mNotesList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    //  gridLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    //gridLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mNotesList.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}


private Query query = fNotesDatabase;
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NoteModel> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NoteModel>()
                .setQuery(query, NoteModel.class)
                .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_notes, parent, false);

        return new NoteViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(final NoteViewHolder holder, int position, NoteModel model) {
        final String noteId = getRef(position).getKey();

        fNotesDatabase.child(noteId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("title") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("timestamp")) {
                    String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
                    String timestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString();

                    holder.setNoteTitle(title);
                    holder.setNoteTime(timestamp);

                    GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                    holder.setNoteTime(getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(timestamp), getApplicationContext()));

                    holder.noteCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(NotesMine.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
        mNotesList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

};




private void updateUI() {
    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        Log.i("MainActivity", "fAuth != null");
    } else {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(NotesMine.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();
        Log.i("MainActivity", "fAuth == null");
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.main_new_note_btn:
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(NotesMine.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}



/**
 * Converting dp to pixel
 */
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

}

Comment: Читайте свежую документацию, изменилась сигнатура конструктора в версии 3.х: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  прошу прощение, но я новичок и до меня просто не доходит как изменить этот блок кода для корректной работы. Возможно вы могли бы мне с этим помочь, если вам конечно не трудно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код должен быть примерно таким:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NoteModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NoteModel>()
                    .setQuery(query, NoteModel.class)
                    .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_notes, parent, false);

        return new NoteViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int position, NoteModel model) {
        // Сюда перенесете код из populateViewHolder()
        // ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Ошибок не выдает но и информацию не отображает.

Comment: информация в базу данных записывается, но не отображается в приложении, что делать ?

Comment: Добавьте перед `.build();` строку `.setLifecycleOwner(NotesMine.this)` или сделайте так https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/firestore/README.md#startstop-listening

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  Вот в чем ошибка. Когда я дохожу до .build(); у меня все переменные все еще равняются null им почему то нечего не присваивается

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Вот мот код на Гите https://github.com/AntipinVlad/ProgLand2.git

Comment: Ваш код не будет никогда работать. Нельзя создавать `options` раньше чем 
 проинициализируется `fNotesDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

Данный код является правильным для этого типа задач:

```
public class NotesMine extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
private RecyclerView mNotesList;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private DatabaseReference fNotesDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    mNotesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.notes_list);

    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mNotesList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mNotesList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mNotesList.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        fNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    }
    updateUI();
    loadData();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

private  void loadData() {
    Query query = fNotesDatabase;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NoteModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<NoteModel>()
                    .setQuery(query, NoteModel.class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(NotesMine.this)
                    .build();

    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_notes, parent, false);

            return new NoteViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(final NoteViewHolder holder, int position, NoteModel model) {
            final String noteId = getRef(position).getKey();

            fNotesDatabase.child(noteId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("title") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("timestamp")) {
                        String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue().toString();
                        String timestamp = dataSnapshot.child("timestamp").getValue().toString();

                        holder.setNoteTitle(title);
                        GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                        holder.setNoteTime(getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(timestamp), getApplicationContext()));

                        holder.noteCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(NotesMine.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("noteId", noteId);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mNotesList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void updateUI() {
    if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        Log.i("MainActivity", "fAuth != null");
    } else {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(NotesMine.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();
        Log.i("MainActivity", "fAuth == null");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.main_new_note_btn:
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(NotesMine.this, NewNoteActivity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
}

}
```